# Where do I find my badge history?

Tags: discussion, support, badges

Where can I find my badge history? I would like to know the date and time I earned a certain badge, the post(s)/edit(s) for which I earned it, along with the current list of all badges I hold.

I did search the questions here, and I hope I have not missed something already answered.

I have recently earned a badge, but I cannot recall its name, nor when exactly I was given it. The count of badges on the status line at the top (16) and in my profile (which says 18, but lists 16) do not seem to tally.

I think that just the right link will take me to the place where all this is explained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

List of badge awards: https://english.stackexchange.com/users/14666/kris?tab=activity&sort=badges

Badge list: https://english.stackexchange.com/users/14666/kris?tab=badges

Note that you've earned 16 different badges, but a total of 18 badges (i.e. you earned two extra *Nice Answer* badges). I believe the header should be showing 2 silver badges and 16 bronze badges for you.

The most recent badge you earned was the [Excavator badge](https://english.stackexchange.com/badges/102/excavator).

Comment: Oh thanks a ton! Yes, I think I have all the details I wanted right there.